Stripna: Pandas dropna but behaves like strip
It is a pretty common occurrence to have leading and trailing NaN values in a table or DataFrame. This is particularly true after joins and in timeseries data.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'b': [np.NaN, 2, np.NaN, 4, 5, np.NaN, np.NaN],
})

Out[0]:
    a   b
0   1   NaN
1   2   2.0
2   3   NaN
3   4   4.0
4   5   5.0
5   6   NaN
6   7   NaN

Let's remove these with dropna.
df1.dropna()

Out[1]:
    a   b
1   2   2.0
3   4   4.0
4   5   5.0

Oh no!! We lost all the missing values that showed in column b. I want to keep the middle (inner) ones.
How do I strip the rows with leading and trailing NaN values in a quick, clean and efficient way? The results should look as follows:
df1.stripna() 
# obviously I'm not asking you to create a new pandas method...
# I just thought it was a good name.

Out[3]:
    a   b
1   2   2.0
2   3   NaN
3   4   4.0
4   5   5.0


Some of the answers so far are pretty nice but I think this is important enough functionality that I raised a feature request with Pandas here if anyone is interested. Let's see how it goes!

Another way, that might be a little more readable is using the pd.Series.first_valid_index and pd.Series.last_valid_index with index slicing using loc:
df1.loc[df1['b'].first_valid_index():df1['b'].last_valid_index()]

Output:
   a    b
1  2  2.0
2  3  NaN
3  4  4.0
4  5  5.0

And, this should be really fast.  Using @LittleBobbyTables input dataframe.
%timeit df1.loc[df1['b'].ffill().notna()&df1['b'].bfill().notna()]


24.2 ms ± 610 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

verus:
%timeit df1.loc[df1['b'].first_valid_index():df1['b'].last_valid_index()]


1.43 ms ± 34.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)


Very nice. The downside of this method, though, is that it gives the wrong result if all values in df1['b'] are np.nan. That would evaluate to df1.loc[None:None], which returns the entire df1, when the expected result should be an empty DataFrame.

@ouroboros1 You could add a check first, like assert df1['b'].first_valid_index() is not None. (No need to check last too since at least one valid first index implies at least one valid last index.) Then you could pack this in a function for easier use.

Both excellent observations and comments about this solution.  Thanks!

@ouroboros1 great catch. For my use case this is almost certainly not an issue, but is an interesting edge case to be aware of.

You could bfill/ffill + isna to build a mask for boolean indexing:
out = df1.loc[df1['b'].ffill().notna()&df1['b'].bfill().notna()]

Alternatively, with interpolate:
out = df1.loc[df1['b'].interpolate(limit_area='inside').notna()]

Or with cummax:
m = df1['b'].notna()
out = df1.loc[m.cummax() & m[::-1].cummax()]

Output:
   a    b
1  2  2.0
2  3  NaN
3  4  4.0
4  5  5.0

Intermediates:
# bfill/fill
   a    b  bfill  ffill  bfill+notna  ffill+notna      &
0  1  NaN    2.0    NaN         True        False  False
1  2  2.0    2.0    2.0         True         True   True
2  3  NaN    4.0    2.0         True         True   True
3  4  4.0    4.0    4.0         True         True   True
4  5  5.0    5.0    5.0         True         True   True
5  6  NaN    NaN    5.0        False         True  False

# cummax
   a    b      m  cummax  reverse_cummax      &
0  1  NaN  False   False            True  False
1  2  2.0   True    True            True   True
2  3  NaN  False    True            True   True
3  4  4.0   True    True            True   True
4  5  5.0   True    True            True   True
5  6  NaN  False    True           False  False


nice work with interpolate, better to interpolate on the notna so it works with all data types.

@QuangHoang I'm not sure how one could proceed. (m:=df1['b'].notna().convert_dtypes()).where(m).interpolate('pad', limit_area='inside').fillna(False) is a bit cumbersome.

Here is a slight refinement to mozway's answer, if you're on pandas>=2.2. You can use ffill with area_limit instead of interpolate.
This should be a bit quicker as interpolate defaults to linear.
out = df1.loc[df1['b'].ffill(limit_area='inside').notna()]

But for pure speed and support across older pandas versions you can't beat Scott Boston's blazingly fast (>10x) first/last_valid_index answer.
df1.loc[df1['b'].first_valid_index():df1['b'].last_valid_index()]


Speed Test!
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': range(1_000_000),
    'b': [
        *([np.NaN] * 100_000),
        *range(100_000, 200_000),
        *([np.NaN] * 100_000),
        *range(300_000, 900_000),
        *([np.NaN] * 100_000),
    ],
})

%timeit
df1.loc[df1['b'].ffill().notna()&df1['b'].bfill().notna()]

Out[1]:
12.3 ms ± 258 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
df1.loc[df1['b'].interpolate(limit_area='inside').notna()]

Out[2]:
55.3 ms ± 1.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
m = df1['b'].notna()
out = df1.loc[m.cummax() & m[::-1].cummax()]

Out[3]:
128 ms ± 3.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
df1.loc[df1['b'].ffill(limit_area='inside').notna()]

Out[4]:
15.4 ms ± 681 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In this case there is a 3.5x speed increase in pandas 2.2 if you use ffill instead of interpolate. Compared to the first example which is fastest, it is a little easier to read.
However, Scott Boston's blazingly fast first/last_valid_index answer blows the competition away and very readable.
%%timeit
df1.loc[df1['b'].first_valid_index():df1['b'].last_valid_index()]

Out[5]:
798 µs ± 55.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

The slight downsides here are that it might return unexpected results (a full DataFrame) if all rows in b are NaNs and that it is also harder to extend to wider use cases (e.g. multiple missing columns).

Good point, I had forgotten about this addition to ffill. Actually, this conincidates with the fact that the ffill/pad behavior of interpolate is getting deprecated ;)

@ScottBoston added. It was even fast on my machine!!

FYI there is a pd.Dataframe.first_valid_index and pd.DataFrame.last_valid_index that will check to see if any of the columns has a non-nan value an return that first/last index.

That's useful to know. That makes your case a bit more extensible! I think df1.loc[df1['b', 'c'].ffill(limit_area='inside').notna().any()] is probably easier to adapt the logic to multiple columns, e.g. replacing any with all.

Solution 1: .isna().cumprod() as bool
This solution:

First creates a boolean mask nans that identifies the NaN entries.

The start mask uses the cumulative product of nans to mark all rows as True until the first non-NaN value is encountered.

The end mask reverses the dataframe, performs a similar cumulative product to identify trailing NaN values.

Finally, the dataframe is filtered by negating the combined masks (~(start | end)), retaining only the rows that are neither leading nor trailing NaN, thus preserving any inner NaN values.


nans = df1['b'].isna()
start = nans.cumprod().astype(bool)
end = nans[::-1].cumprod().astype(bool)

df1[~(start | end)]


Solution 2: .notna().cumsum().gt(0)
This solution:

Begins by creating a boolean mask notnans that identifies non-NaN entries in column b.

The expression notnans.cumsum().gt(0) generates a mask that marks all rows as True starting from the first non-NaN value onward.

notnans[::-1].cumsum().gt(0) reverses the boolean mask to perform a cumulative sum from the end, marking rows as True until the last non-NaN value is encountered.

The final filtering retains rows where both conditions are True.


notnans = df1['b'].notna() 
df1[(notnans.cumsum().gt(0)) & (notnans[::-1].cumsum().gt(0))]


NB: @wjandrea obeserves, in a comment below and very interestingly, that the reversed series do not need to be reversed back, since the indexing guarantees the correct alignment of the series.

Output:
   a    b
1  2  2.0
2  3  NaN
3  4  4.0
4  5  5.0


Yes, this literally solves the problem shown by the very specific example I gave above but the concept is much more, "how to strip multiple leading and trailing NaN values?"

This seems pretty difficult to extend to an unknown number of outer NaNs.

That is not difficult to adapt my approach to that setting, @LittleBobbyTables. I will do that later, as now I must leave the computer.

I extended my question as well for completeness! Looking forward to it :)

I have updated my solution, which now should work in the general setting you need, @LittleBobbyTables.

When writing an answer, code is helpful, but a short description of how it works is also important (sometimes just as important) for understanding how it works. I added descriptions for you :)

Thanks, @wjandrea! I am going to add an explanation.

You don't actually need to reverse back, since Pandas will align on the index, which is preserved through the first reversal

Thanks, @wjandrea! I did not know about it, but is indeed a nice thing to learn!

FWIW, I prefer .gt() over > for chaining: df1[notnans.cumsum().gt(0) & notnans[::-1].cumsum().gt(0)]. It's easier to read and write since you don't need to wrap parentheses around whole expressions.

Thanks again, @wjandrea. Actually, I also prefer that, but this time that escaped to my attention!
